# Measure Theory - Folland - Problem 2.7

Tags: measure-theory

This is a problem from Real Analysis - Modern Techniques and Their Applications, by Folland. I'm trying my best here, but it's hard to solve.

[image]

PS: The measurable space is $(X,\mathcal{M})$.

To me, the function should be $f(x) = \inf\{\alpha: x\in E_\alpha \} = \sup\{\alpha: x\in E_\alpha^c \}$. I'm not entirely sure about this last equality, but I guess it's ok (I would prove this for last if all goes well, which is not the case). Anyway, the point is that $E_\alpha \subset f^{-1}((-\infty, \alpha])$, for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. My hope was to prove that $f^{-1}((-\infty, \alpha])\backslash E_\alpha = \emptyset$, therefore $f^{-1}((-\infty, \alpha]) = E_\alpha \in \mathcal{M}$. But this is not necessarily true because it's possible to have points $x\in E_\alpha^c$ such that $f(x) = \alpha$.

In addition to this problem, my idea is not using exercise 4, given below.

[image]

I need to know how to fix this or what is the correct solution, if mine is wrong. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try $f(x)=\inf\{q\in\mathbb Q: x\in E_q\}$.

Comment: I thought about this. The next step would be to show that $f^{-1}([r,\infty))$ or $f^{-1}((-\infty, r])$ is measurable right? In this case don't I have the same problem on $f(r)$ ?

Comment: You can write $f^{-1}[q,\infty)=\left(\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb Q,r<q}  E_r\right)^c$.