# Folland Chapter 2 Exercise 7

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm working on the problem linked here:
[Measure Theory - Folland - Problem 2.7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085050/measure-theory-folland-problem-2-7) For completeness, I restate it here:

> Suppose that for each $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ we are given a set $E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $E_{\alpha} \subset E_{\beta}$ whenever $\alpha < \beta$, $\bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}E_{\alpha}=X$, and $\bigcap_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}E_{\alpha}=\emptyset$. Then there is a measurable function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \leq \alpha$ on $E_{\alpha}$ and $f(x) \geq \alpha$ on $E_{\alpha}^C$ for all $\alpha$.

A poster suggests trying: $f(x) = \inf\{q \in \mathbb{Q} | x \in E_q\}$. I'm failing to see how this satisfies $f(x) \leq \alpha$ on $E_{\alpha}$. In fact, I'm having trouble interpreting what $\inf\{q \in \mathbb{Q} | x \in E_q\}$ is. Is this function taking "the interior rational level sets" and finding a minimum of $f(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x \in E_\alpha$. Then $x \in E_\beta$ for all $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}, \beta > \alpha$. Therefore, $f(x) \le \beta$ for all $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}, \beta > \alpha$. Hence, $f(x) \le \alpha$. Now take $x \in E_\alpha^C$. Then $x \in E_\beta$ for all $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}, \beta < \alpha$. So, $f(x) \ge \beta$ for all $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}, \beta < \alpha$ and hence, $f(x) \ge \alpha$. We've shown $f^{-1}([\alpha,\infty)) = E_\alpha^C$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. This shows $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Just from the first 4 sentences of your post: can we conclude also that $f^{-1}((-\infty,\alpha])=E_\alpha$ as well?

Comment: The answer will be no, I think

Comment: No. The first 4 show that $f^{-1}((-\infty,\alpha]) \supseteq E_\alpha$. You need all to get equality.

Comment: Also, I found it hard to think about what $f$ is. Just pretend the $E_\alpha$'s are a bunch of interiors of circles, lying within one another. You're defining $f(x)$, basically, to be the (index of the) smallest circle that $x$ lies in.

Comment: I have trouble following your proof, how does $f(x) \ge \beta$  for all $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}, \beta < \alpha$ imply $f(x) \ge \alpha$ when $\beta < \alpha$? Does $f(x) \ge 2$ necessarily imply $f(x) \ge 4$?

Comment: @Abel So the claim is that $f(x) \ge \beta$ for all $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}, \beta < \alpha$ implies $f(x) \ge \alpha$. This claim follows from the fact any given $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$ can be approximated arbitrarily well by numbers $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}, \beta < \alpha$. Formally, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}, \beta < \alpha$ with $\beta > \alpha-\epsilon$. You might have heard the related "the rationals are dense in the reals". This is all stuff one should know before starting measure theory, though.